# What is the uriTemplate for my case?

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I am implement the service as

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost/xyzServices/xyzService.svc/";
var request = new RestRequest("{facilityId}/xyzs/metadata/", Method.POST);
request.AddUrlSegment("facilityId", "111");
request.AddParameter("xyzIds", _xyzIds.ToArray());
```

Now what is the right uriTemplate in the svc code then?

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate =
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figure it out.

```
UriTemplate = "/{FacilityId}/xyzs/metadata/")];
```